# Excel =MATCH function returning less cells than it should be

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use the MATCH function (=MATCH(K1,B:B,0)) to return the number of cells with my criteria K1, and it is only returning 3 when I clearly see more than 3 (almost 20). I thought this was due to the fact that the formatting of my criteria and the array were different (I pasted in my array), so I created column B using the paste special>add method, which I had seen somewhere. This didn't help, so I tried manually inputting the column B data, and the MATCH function still returned 3. Lastly, I tried to check if the formats were the same between my K1 and column B so I utilized =K1=B1 (to check if they were the same), and they all returned TRUE. I am unsure how to proceed at this point.

Also wanted to add that I want to be able to easily use this file in the future when I add more data so that when I add the data, all I have to do is drag the formulas down and everything will be sorted. This file is going to someone else, so they need to be able to use it.

Comment: Match does not return the number of matches, use `COUNTIFS()` for that.  It returns the relative location of the FIRST match in the range.  So in this case the match is being found in row 3 of `B:B`